# How to create a file Path from a folder Path

Tags: java, nio

I am probably overlooking something but what's the right way to create a file `Path` from a folder `Path`? This is what I'm doing but it seems wrong to convert the folder path to a string just to reconstruct it. Is there a better way?

```
Path testFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("fileFinder");
Path testFile = Paths.get(testFolder.toString(), "sample.java");
Files.createFile(testFile);
```

Comment: `testfolder.resolve("sample.java")` ?

Comment: @PM77-1 that was it, do you want to write it as an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html) class has [`resolve()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.lang.String)) method to join two paths together. It is overloaded to take a String as a parameter (*other path*).

So your expression to produce the combined path will be:

```
testfolder.resolve("sample.java")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Path testFile = Files.createFile(Files.createTempDirectory("fileFinder").resolve("sample.java"));
```

But maybe all you need is just one tempfile:

```
Path testFile = Files.createTempFile("fileFinder");
```